# hover changes style of unrelated element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I am trying to make an element appear (or disappear) when I hover over an unrelated element.

At the moment I am trying to do this using lists and indexes such that the nth item in list 2 is changes when the nth item in list 1 is hovered. This would give a general solution for many objects rather than pairing all the elements and writing a jQuery rule for each. I have looked at other discussions but none seem to have a general solution.

Below is some toy code which I have tried this with.

I am very new to jQuery so thanks for being patient.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>addClass demo</title>
<style>
.disappear { display: none }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class = "one">Hello</li>
            <li class = "one">and</li>
            <li class = "one">Goodbye</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class = "two">Hello</li>
            <li class = "two">and</li>
            <li class = "two">Goodbye</li>
        </ul>
<script>
$( "li one" ).on('mouseenter', function() {
 var indx = $(this).eq();
 $("li two").eq(indx).addClass("disapear");
}); 
$( "li" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
 $(this).removeClass("disappear");
}); 
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all use $( "li .one" ) in steand of $( "li one" ). The '.' say its a class

Comment: @user2348221 You are almost correct, this `$( "li .one" )` would be selecting an li with a child who has the class `.one`. The correct way is as followed, `$( "li.one" )`. (If you put a space between them it is separating them)

Comment: It seems that you are looking at only hiding a specific object, but once its hidden, the next visible one assumes its index... might it that be the problem? Ex: ndx1, ndx2, ndx3; Once ndx2 is hidden, ndx3 is ndx2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem

1. You have misspelled class. its `disappear` instead of `disapear`
2. Use `$("li.one")` instead of `$( "li one" )` and `$("li.two")` instead of `$( "li two" )`
3. Use `index()` instead of `eq()`
4. Use `.hover()`, I recommnend

Code

```
$("li.one").hover(function () {
    var indx = $(this).index();
    $("li.two").eq(indx).addClass("disappear");
}, function () {
    var indx = $(this).index();
    $("li.two").eq(indx).removeClass("disappear");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Av6zJ/)

Answer (score 0):

`eq()` will not tell you the index of the current element (see http://api.jquery.com/eq/ ). Its behaviour without a parameter isn't defined, in fact.

You want `index()` for that, so:

```
var indx = $(this).index();
$("li.two").eq(indx).addClass("disappear");
```

Note that your original code also had a typo: `disapear` for `disappear` in one but not both cases.

Furthermore you want `"li.one"` and `"li.two"` to select elements with those classes, not `"li one"` - the dot is the class selector.

You might consider putting the class on the `<ul>` instead, and doing `"ul.one li"`